# Xcode7 swift2 - double tap on MKMapView is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code and no error when I run this. long press is working fine and double tap is not working. I have disabled the zoom before adding the double tap gesture.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    manager  = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    routeMapView.zoomEnabled = false
    routeMapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "routeMapDoubleTapSelector:")
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    routeMapView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    let ulpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"routeMapLongPressSelector:")
    ulpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    routeMapView.addGestureRecognizer(ulpgr)


}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it seem to be working fine. "double taps" is printed. Here's the test code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let routeMapView = MKMapView()
    self.view = routeMapView

    routeMapView.zoomEnabled = false
    routeMapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "routeMapDoubleTapSelector:")
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    routeMapView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    let ulpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"routeMapLongPressSelector:")
    ulpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    routeMapView.addGestureRecognizer(ulpgr)
}

func routeMapDoubleTapSelector(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("double taps")
}

func routeMapLongPressSelector(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("long press")
}
}
```

Comment: it works now. I have removed "if gestureRecognizer.state" condition in the doubleTap selector method. Thank you for your help.